# After launch PDF file close the tab in which link of PDF (Android)

Tags: android, google-chrome, pdf

I'm working on Android application in which, when i post some parameters it generates PDF on run-time and show PDF output. Web-view has failed to give output in this scenario.So i started to launch on chrome browser directly.
**"I want when this link launched completely then particular (in which the PDF link has launched) tab of chrome will auto close."** 
Please note (google docs link to view PDF is not working in this scenario).
Feel free to ask any question regarding understanding of this question.
Please suggest, is it possible & please suggest, other solutions if possible.
**Please note, this pdf is generating on run time after getting parameters**
Thank you :)

Comment: do you required to open pdf in webview or chrome only?

Comment: Thank you for taking interest.
I have tried several different ways to open in webview but i failded to do it,
If it can open in webview it will be pretty good.Else only open this is PDF and after launch close tab.

Comment: you can use this library https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer
instead of webivew or chrome.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, it is not working is my case.